# need to know how to install Lux API in python

Tags: python, api, installation, pip, helper

How would one install `Lux API` in Python?

I've used the following procedure:
`pip install lux-api`

But when I run:

```
jupyter nbextension install --py luxwidget
jupyter nbextension enable --py luxwidget
```

It shows:

```
Invalid syntax.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using 'jupyter command' in notebook. I did the same.
When you do it on cmd. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

!jupyter nbextension install --py luxwidget
!jupyter nbextension enable --py luxwidget